# Show that the K-Means algorithm will update a clustering C in such a way that one cluster becomes empty even though it had at least one point in C?

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means, data-mining

[image]

This is the K-means Algorithm, which recieves a 2D-numpy array D with k clusters and a termination criterion eps. I need to show an example where a Cluster that is updated becomes empty, yet in every example I've tried this doesn't happen. **I cannot create the clusters and begin the iteration, I must begin with the means and k.**

I've tried to change the value of k, change the value of the means. But nothing has worked so far.

This is the code I'm implementing in python (mu are the means, or *centroids* as they are called in the image above):

```
def kMeans(D, k, eps, mu = None):

t = 0

if mu == None:        
    mu = []
    for a in range(k):
        mu.append(np.random.randint(np.min(D), np.max(D), size = (1,2))[0].tolist())

MuD = eps + 0.1
    
while (MuD > eps):
    
    MuAnterior = mu.copy()
    C = []
    
    t += 1
    clusters = [[] for _ in range(k)]
    
    for c in range(len(D)):
        dist = [[] for _ in range(k)]
        
        for d in range(k):
            dist[d].append(pow(distance.euclidean(D[c], mu[d]),2))
        
        clusters[np.argmin(dist)].append(D[c])
        C.append(np.argmin(dist))

    for e in range(k):
        suma = 0
        for f in range(len(clusters[e])):  
            suma += clusters[e][f]
        if len(clusters[e]) != 0:
            mu[e] = (suma/len(clusters[e])).tolist()
        else:
            mu[e] = [0, 0]
    
    MuD = 0
    for a in range(k):
        MuD += pow(distance.euclidean(mu[a], MuAnterior[a]),2)


return C, mu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1D, with initial clusters [0], [1, 5], [6], the first step will update to [0, 1], [], [5, 6].